# Change word in string PHP, but i don't know the word

Tags: php, string, replace

I have a string and I must to replace the month with another word (I had to translate the month to Italian). The problem is that I don'know what is the month in string **$intervallo**

I try with this code but doesn't work... please can you give me suggestions?

Thanks!

```
$intervallo= " 22 July-28 July 2015";

$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("January","Gennaio",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("February","Febbraio",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("March","Marzo",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("April","Aprile",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("May","Maggio",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("June","Giugno",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("July","Luglio",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("August","Agosto",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("September","Settembre",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("October","Ottobre",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("November","Novembre",$intervallo);
$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace("December","Dicembre",$intervallo);
```

Answer (score 6):

@mmm's answer is correct, but there is a simpler way to this which is less error prone:

```
$intervallo = " 22 July-28 July 2015";
$search = Array('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December');
$replace = Array('Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre');

$settimana= "Attivita' settimana".str_replace($search, $replace, $intervallo);
```

Answer (score 2):

all the remplacements are on the same variable so you have to do this :

```
$intervallo = str_replace("January","Gennaio",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("February","Febbraio",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("March","Marzo",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("April","Aprile",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("May","Maggio",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("June","Giugno",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("July","Luglio",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("August","Agosto",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("September","Settembre",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("October","Ottobre",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("November","Novembre",$intervallo);
$intervallo = str_replace("December","Dicembre",$intervallo);

$settimana = "Attivita' settimana" . $intervallo;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will only work for December, since each line overwrites whatever replacement occurred from the previous line.  I find that replacements of the form you're doing work well with `str_replace()`'s array handling:

```
$intervallo= " 22 July-28 July 2015";

$settimana = str_replace(
    array( 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December' ),
    array( 'Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre' ),
    $intervallo
);
```

This works by replacing each value in the first array with its corresponding value in the second array.

Answer (score 0):

To minimise repetition you should iterate through the months.

```
$months = array(
    array(
        'english' => 'January',
        'italian' => 'Gennaio'
    ),
    array(
        'english' => 'February',
        'italian' => 'Febbraio'
    ),
    array(
        'english' => 'March',
        'italian' => 'Marzo'
    ),
    ...
);

$intervallo = " 22 July-28 July 2015";

foreach ($months as $month) {
    $intervallo = str_replace($month['english'], $month['italian'], $intervallo);
}

$settimana = "Attivita' settimana" . $intervallo;
```

This solution also means that if another language is thrown into the mix at some point it will be a lot simpler to refactor the code.